# Добавить элемент внутрь уже сформорованной таблицы на html

Tags: jquery, массивы, html, append, javascript

Здравствуйте, есть проблема которую я не могу решить таки длительное время, проблема заключается в создании нового элемента td и размещении его внутри tr

В общем, у меня есть таблица

```
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
</tr>
```

выглядит она так

```
|1|2|3|
|1|2|3|
```

а еще есть массив элементов 
var arr = [1, 2];

В итоге мне нужно получить примерно такое

```
|1|2|3|element[0]
|1|2|3|element[1]
```

Были у меня примеры кода с использование вложенных циклов, но ничего не вышло, есть идеи?

Answer (score 2):

Если правильно понял, то так:

```
var data = [4, 4];

$('tr').each(function(i, el) {
    if(i < data.length)
        $(el).append('<td>' + data[i] + '</td>');
});
```

Демо: http://jsfiddle.net/AmXd6/

Comment: У меня получается массив с четными ключами, когда делаю проверку на четность то пропадает 1 элемент.

Comment: @thextest: В Вашем вопросе ни слова о четности. Конкретизируйте, что Вам нужно. В моем примере в таблицу вставляется столько значений, сколько равно `min(количество строк таблицы, количество элементов в массиве)`

Answer (score 0):

Первый вариант нерабочий. Вот рабочий вариант. Далее модифицируйте как нравится.

```html
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">

</script>
<table>
<tr id='row_0'>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr id='row_1'>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
</tr>
</table>
<script>
$("#row_0").append("4");
$("#row_1").append("4");
</script>
```